# Website background interfering with website content

Tags: html, css, pdf, web

I'm sure this is a basic question but I am a complete beginner so sorry ahead of time! I am building a website and I decided to add an image as my background with this code:

```css
#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height:100%;
    background-image: url('/images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size:cover;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
```

However, when I add this, it doesn't allow me to interact with my contact me script or my embedded PDF.

code for pdf:

```
<center>
<iframe id="iframepdf" src="/documents/Resume.pdf" width="783px" height="1009"></iframe>
</center>
```

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you include the code for the "contact me script" and the "embedded PDF"? Are these all on the same HTML page?

Comment: Sure, thanks for helping. I don't have the code for the contact me form right now, but the PDF is 

 ' <center><iframe id="iframepdf" src="/documents/Resume.pdf" width="783px" height="1009"></iframe></center>'

And no, the CSS is a separate file, and the embedded PDF is on a different page than the form.

Comment: please edit your question to include contact form code or do a mock-up on http://www.jsbin.com

Comment: do you want the image to just cover a div or the whole page?, like are your header and footer styled differently?

Comment: I'd like for it to cover the whole page, just not overlap the embedded content.

Comment: Read the tag-descriptions!

Answer (score 0):

for a start you have way too much stuff in your background image css. If you want to cover a div, then use the div tag but if you want to cover the whole page

use

```
body {
    background-image: url('/images/background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks; I reduced it to
'#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('/images/background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}'

Comment: you don't need the width and height with background:cover; you don't need the rest of it either

Answer (score 0):

The div you are using as your background is probably getting in the way of other things in the website. I would suggest using the  tag for your background image

```css
body{
  background-image:url(background.jpg)
}
```

Comment: This did work.. however, what if I wanted to add different backgrounds to different pages or change the settings for this background?